# Use two command in source file awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to write a .awk source file to filter a .txt and I wanted to know how do I use the max variable after in the second command

```
BEGIN {max1=0}
```

## Find the max value in $4 between two patterns (0 and 1) and set it as a variable

```
{if ($4>0 && $4<1)
max1=$4
else if ($4==1)
max=max1}
END {print max}

/Nodes/ {f=1} /EndNodes/ {f=0} #Gives lines after Nodes and before EndNodes
{if ($2+0>=0 && $3+0==0 && max==$4)  #Filters the given lines between Nodes and EndNodes
{print $1}}
```

My guess is that i need to run the program from start after the max variable is defined (because it uses the same lines as the second command.

The desire output should be: 20, 31 and 32

**INPUT**

```
$Nodes
  34
   1  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000
   2  6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000
   3  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000
   4 -6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000
   5  0.0000000E+000 -6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000
   6  2.1213203E-003  2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
   7 -2.1213203E-003  2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
   8 -2.1213203E-003 -2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
   9  2.1213203E-003 -2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
  10  4.2426407E-003  4.2426407E-003  0.0000000E+000
  11 -4.2426407E-003  4.2426407E-003  0.0000000E+000
  12 -4.2426407E-003 -4.2426407E-003  0.0000000E+000
  13  4.2426407E-003 -4.2426407E-003  0.0000000E+000
  14  2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000
  15  0.0000000E+000  2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
  16 -2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000
  17  0.0000000E+000 -2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000
  18  0.0000000E+000  2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
  19  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003  6.0000000E-003
  20  0.0000000E+000  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003
  21 -4.2426407E-003  4.2426407E-003  6.0000000E-003
  22 -2.1213203E-003  2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
  23 -6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003
  24 -2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003
  25 -4.2426407E-003 -4.2426407E-003  6.0000000E-003
  26 -2.1213203E-003 -2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
  27  0.0000000E+000 -6.0000000E-003  6.0000000E-003
  28  0.0000000E+000 -2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
  29  4.2426407E-003 -4.2426407E-003  6.0000000E-003
  30  2.1213203E-003 -2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
  31  6.0000000E-003  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003
  32  2.1213203E-003  0.0000000E+000  6.0000000E-003
  33  4.2426407E-003  4.2426407E-003  6.0000000E-003
  34  2.1213203E-003  2.1213203E-003  6.0000000E-003
$EndNodes
$Elements
#And some more data
$EndElements
```

Comment: General rule: If you ask an `awk` question then provide test input and the desired output.

Comment: It is unfortunately very unclear from your `awk` code what it is that you'd want to do. Could you please explain with words?

Comment: Did you get the code from someone/somewhere else?

Comment: I am new to programming. The first code until END {print max} prints out the max value of the $4 between Nodes and EndNodes. The second gives the lines between the two patterns "Nodes" and "EndNodes" and then filter the node number from points with positive x value, y value 0 and the max z value (in a cartesian coordiante system). Both codes work fine alone, but I need to set the variable max to filter then the Node numbers for the points. I did the code myself

Comment: More general rules: (1) Use two-digit numbers in your example.  One-digit numbers don’t provide enough variety, but when I see eleven-digit numbers, I just go on to the next question.  (2) If at all possible, make your *total* example fit into the data pane without scrolling — i.e., no more than about 32 lines.  (3) *Explain* how your desired output corresponds to the input.  I have no idea how you get 20, 31 and 32 from that 40-line block of eleven-digit numbers.  (4) Make your  desired output correspond to the problem statement.  How does ‘‘Find the max value’’ get three results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a one-pass solution:

```
/Nodes/         { read = 1 }
/EndNodes/      { read = 0 }

!read           { next     }

NF == 4                         { n = $1; x = $2; y = $3; z = $4 }
z > max                         { delete set; i = 1; max = z     }
x >= 0 && y == 0 && z == max    { set[i++] = n                   }

END             { for (i in set) { print set[i] } }
```

The `read` variable determines if we should act on the current record or not. If it's 1, then we do.

The 3rd block discards the current input if we're not interested in it and continues from the top with the next record.

The 4th block sets up four convenience variables, `n`, `x`, `y` and `z`. They are nicer to read than `$1` etc.

The 5th block deletes the array `set`.  The `set` array is the set of all node numbers that we've found so far and that fulfill the criteria.  Since this block executes if we've found a new maximum for `z`, all previously found nodes are invalidated. We also save the new maximum (`max`).  The variable `i` is just an index into the array (a counter, basically). If no maximum has yet been found, then the uninitialized `max` will be treated as zero in the test.

The 6th block executes when we've found a node that fulfills the criteria.  The node number is saved in the `set` array and `i` is incremented.

At the end, we loop through the `set` array and output its contents.

The result when running under GNU `awk` is

```
20
31
32
```

BSD `awk` and `mawk` running on OpenBSD produces the list in the opposite order.

Comment: Thank you so much for doing it simple and describe it in a way I could understand, sorry for not being precise enough

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

***get_max_nodes.awk*** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{ max=0 }
NR==FNR{                         # processing the 1st input file
    if ($4~/^[0-9]/) {           # if the 4th field is a number
        if($4+0 > max) max=$4+0  # capturing maximal number
    }
    next
}
{   # processing the 2nd input file (same file)
    if ($4~/^[0-9]/ && $2+0>=0 && $3+0==0 && $4+0==max) {
        print $1
    }
}
```

*Usage:*

```
awk -f get_max_nodes.awk input.txt input.txt
```

The output:

```
20
31
32
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough reputation to comment, so I am forced to respond with an answer.  My first comment would have been that awk is not the best tool for doing real number math.  It is better at strings and integer numbers.

Other points on awk:  The BEGIN paragraph happens before any lines are read from your input.  The END paragraph happens after all lines have been read.

Note: awk does not save or care about anything except the current line/record of input, unless you take steps to store the records/fields within your code.  This needs to happen between BEGIN and END.

Your code between these paragraphs is only setting/resetting variables but doing nothing with their values.  Essentially, you could tail -1 your input file and pipe the output to cut, to achieve similar results.

It seems that your intention is to test the number in column 4 to find max or max1, and only print column 1 if the column 4 contains this max followed by successful testing of column 2 and 3.  This logic needs to be moved before the END unless you only care about the last line of the file.

Remember, in awk, every line of input (by default) is compared against every condition.  If the condition is true, the action or list of actions is executed.  It is highly possible to have multiple conditions trigger actions on the same line.

My first impression is that you need to re-evaluate your process.  Decide the order of importance and take actions accordingly.  For example, to me, the first order of importance is only acting on the data between two flags in my input file.  Next, Determine if real numbers in each of the 4 fields may be converted to (or treated as) integers (or strings) without losing their meaning.  The actual data itself does not need to change, just its representation within your code. These could be converted back again but the probability of losing accuracy of the original number is high.  Lastly, choose whether or not you need to store all/any of this unsorted, random data for later processing, or give immediate per line output.

The following meta example could be done much more efficiently...
Begin with a flag to let you know if it is time to start parsing.  Have you seen the $0 ~= /Nodes/ line yet?  start=0.  You may also want to prep for knowing when to stop parsing data by testing for $0 ~= /EndNodes/ line, stop=0.  And you might want a counter if you are storing data, count=0.

```
BEGIN {
   start=0
   stop=0
   count=0
   max=0
}
/EndNodes/ {
   stop=1
}
/Nodes/ {
   start=1
}
NF==4 {
   if (start==1 && stop==0) {
      count++
      column1[count]=$1
      column2[count]=substr($2,1,index($2,".")-1)
      column3[count]=substr($3,1,index($3,".")-1)
      column4[count]=substr($4,1,index($4,".")-1)
   }
}
# Now print column1 if column2 is non-negative and column3=0 and column4=max
# In the first loop through the array/list, find max
END {
   for (loop=1;loop<=count;loop++) {
      if (column4[loop]>max) {
         max=column4[loop]
      }
   }
   for (loop=1;loop<=count;loop++) {
      if (column4[loop]==max && column3[loop]==0 && column2[loop]>=0) {
         print column1[loop]
      }
   }
}
```

As written, the output will be

```
20
31
32
```